# Access cognito credentials when consuming kinesis stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have a Kinesis stream consuming some data from a client that is authenticated using Cognito.  I need to validate some of the data based on the user that submitted it.  Is it possible to access the principal from the Lambda consuming the stream in order to validate that data?

Comment: Try logging a record in the lambda (event.Records[0]) and see if there is any info. I think not but haven't tested it